# How to Decode HTML Entities (“&#13;” and " &#163;") from string in xcode

Tags: ios, xml, tbxml

in xml data is

```
<content_special>
    SAT 17TH TEST test club cheap drinks £3 shots £5 bottles $beers
</content_special>
```

i get this string using this code

```
TBXMLElement *Content_Special=[TBXML childElementNamed:@"content_special" parentElement:Club];
            NSString *Content_SpecialStr = [TBXML textForElement:Content_Special];
```

when i `NSLog(@"Content_special:%@",Content_SpecialStr);`

that print like this

```
 Content_special:SAT 17TH TEST&#13;
test club&#13;
cheap drinks&#13;
&#13;
&#163;3 shots&#13;
&#163;5 bottles&#13;
&#13;
$beers
```

how can i get original sting which Display in Xlm ? Any suggestion...

Comment: It says in your title that you can't use NSUTF8StringEncoding... why? Using UTF8 or less preferably, Unicode, would be the solution as ASCII doesn't contain the euro character....

Comment: Found Solution Using Google Toolbox for Mac GTMNSString+HTML.h ,GTMNSString+HTML.m And GTMDefines.h, First #import "GTMNSString+HTML.h"
use like This: Content_SpecialStr = [Content_SpecialStr gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];

Comment: You can post it as an answer if thats the solution, even though its your own answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found Solution Using Google Toolbox for Mac [GTMNSString+HTML.h](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.h) ,[GTMNSString+HTML.m](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.m) And [GTMDefines.h](http://google-toolbox-for-mac.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/GTMDefines.h),

First `#import "GTMNSString+HTML.h"`

use like This: `Content_SpecialStr = [Content_SpecialStr gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your data xml file has utf-8 encoding http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp